# How to run vagrant up in debian wsl in windows terminal

Tags: debian, vagrant, windows-subsystem-for-linux, homestead, windows-terminal

I want to run vagrant up in debian wsl from windows terminal
I have installed vagrant

```
/mnt/c/HS_DEV/Homestead$ vagrant --version
```

I get

*Vagrant 2.2.6*

So im trying to run vagrant up

And i'm getting

```
The executable 'cmd.exe' Vagrant is trying to run was not
found in the PATH variable. This is an error. Please verify
this software is installed and on the path.
```

So i'm trying to use debian.exe instead of the default cmd.exe in the config of windows terminal.
But is still not working, Did someone have an idea on how to do it or what the issue came from. If you have more question on the config i have, i will answer it.

Also i'ts working if i use powershell or cmd.exe, and i'ts working with gitbash as well, but i want to do it in my debian wsl

Comment: Could I recommend that you post this over on [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com) or [SuperUser](https://superuser.com)?  This doesn't really fit with Stack Overflow's "programming" focus.  Give me a reply here with a link to the question on one of those sites, and I can give you what I think the answer is there.  Apologies - Just trying to break myself of the habit of answering questions that don't really belong here.  Thanks!

Comment: How can i know that my question don't belong in SO, also i added tags of my technologies, i added vagrant, wsl, windows terminal in tags so i thought my question was relevant here. And there is my like because i hope to get an anwser https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/626767/how-to-run-vagrant-up-in-debian-wsl-in-windows-terminal

Comment: Regarding "How can I know", when you post a question on any of the StackExchange sites, it has some information there about what would make it a good question.  For Stack Overflow, one of the criteria that is says (while on the question screen) is "specific coding, algorithm, or language problems."  Then there's a link for more information if you "Have a non-programming question."  From there, one of the places it suggests is SuperUser.

Answer (score 0):

First identify where the vagrant.exe file is located i.e.:

```
/mnt/c/Hashicorp/Vagrant/bin
```

Then run:

```
export PATH="$PATH:/mnt/c/Hashicorp/Vagrant/bin"
```

Comment: I change the path, but i still get the same error, just to clarify, i use the path of vagrant from windows instalation , but i have two version of vagrant, the windows version and the debian one, i also try to uninstall vagrant version from windows, but i still get the same error

Comment: Also there is a duplicate of the question in https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/626767/how-to-run-vagrant-up-in-debian-wsl-in-windows-terminal/626811#626811

Comment: And i checked that i can access to the vagrant.exe in my windows files. So i don't know why is it not working

Comment: How are you running vagrant up, you shouldn't need to reference cmd.exe

Comment: I run it in my Homestead directory. I don't want to use cmd.exe, but i keep getting the same error

Comment: If you want to use the Debian version, do the opposite of what I put in the solution and take the path to the Windows exe OUT of the path environmental variable.

Comment: i try some export path that you can see in https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/626767/how-to-run-vagrant-up-in-debian-wsl-in-windows-terminal/626811#626811

Comment: Can you post your current PATH variable?

Comment: My cuurent path variable is ```/usr/bin/vagrant:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin``` and when i do ```which vagrant``` i get ```/usr/bin/vagrant``` but it's constantly changing since i try to debug it